# After schema changes, do not sync records prior to re-provision

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

Note: user only works in Staging DB; Production DB is for viewing only.

When we started those two database were exactly same, so provision databases and sync were working fine.

[image]

Then problem starts when I change schema (while users are still working on staging db). Here is my steps.

1. ***Rows are add/update/delete in Staging (by users)***
2. Deprovision database
3. Add/update columns to tables
4. Re-provision databases again

After deprovision and reprovision, my database becomes inconsistent.

[image]

Now changes ***prior to re-provision*** are not synced to Production DB. SF only keeps track (in tracking table) of rows after provision.

***My Work Around*** - I force to updated each row in each table (so that sync framwork thinks row is updated). However, it takes few hours to sync first time after re-provision.

**Question - Is this what Sync framework supposed/designed to work?**

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the changes made after you deprovision and before you reprovisioned is not retrieved because the triggers and tracking table are not there to track the changes.

it's taking longer as you probably running into conflicts.

prior to deprovisioning and reprovisioning, you may have a identical tables in terms of the rows it contains.

so let's say you have 1M rows on source and destination.

Now you deprovision, so Sync Fx wipes out the knowledge of what was synched.
You reprovision and Sync Fx repopulates the tracking tables with new metadata (1M rows plus or minus newly inserted or deleted rows).

Now Sync Fx has no idea that the data in the source is more or less the same data it already has on the destination.

so it sends the 1M+ rows to the destination, as they get applied, you get PK violations because the rows already exists.

i can see you modified the schema on the source, but you're still synching the same set of columns? if you the new/deleted columns are not part of the scope, you dont have to deprovision. you only deprovision or reprovision if you want to effect the schema changes in the scope definition.

Answer (score 1):

The way it is supposed to work:

If you are going to completely deprovision and re-provision one database then Sync Framework expects you to re-initialize the other database(s) as well. That means take a backup of your "primary" database after (re)provisioning and copy & restore it to your secondaries, followed by running the PostRestoreFixup on it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.data.sqlserver.sqlsyncstorerestore.performpostrestorefixup.aspx).

The alternate method:

There is a work-around to modify the scope in-place instead of deprovisioning and re-provisioning. JuneT created the outline of how to get started on it in a series of blog posts starting here: http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/modifying-sync-framework-scope-definition-part-1-introduction/.

To address your situation specifically:

It sounds like the crux of the problem you are running into may be that the schema changes and deprovision/re-provision are happening when there are un-synced local changes in your staging database. You may be able to fix most of the issues you are experiencing by ensuring that you run a sync just before making the schema changes and doing the deprovision/re-provision. If that is feasible, it may be simpler than the other options.